# Access To Moderator Tools page in Help Center incorrectly links to Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, help-center

I was reading the [Access To Moderator Tools page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and noticed that a link incorrectly points to the Meta site.

---

[image: review queue link]

---

The link in red above points to:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

but should be

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

Not a huge deal, but it might be a little confusing since the MSO privileges are awarded at different rep level than the SO ones.

Comment: This actually applies to all sites - going to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools and clicking on the same link results in ending up on MSO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks - this was my mistake; just got a bit sloppy when editing.

It should now point to the proper location on every site.